# ElunaLuaEngine need help wi-th script

Tags: lua, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I would like to create a script using the [Eluna Lua Engine](http://www.elunaengine.com/) that implements the following:

If a player has an item `192021` in his inventory, then he will be able to talk to npc `202020` and take quest `36004`. And if a player doesn't have an item `192021`, then there is no dialogue.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by "task". Did you mean Quest? please update your question

Comment: Yes, quest.
Player have item 192021 - and he can take a quest from NPC 202020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to do in SQL instead of LUA

It is possible to do it with the table [conditions](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/conditions)

```sql
    SET
        @QUESTID := ,
        @ITEMID := ,
        @ITEMCOUNT := ,
        @COMMENT := 'My Super Condition!';
    INSERT INTO `conditions` (SourceTypeOrReferenceId, SourceGroup, SourceEntry, SourceId, ElseGroup, ConditionTypeOrReference, ConditionValue1, ConditionValue2)
        VALUES
        (19, 0, @QUESTID, 0, 0, 2, @ITEMID, @ITEMCOUNT, @COMMENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an item restriction in any menu by simply adding it to the GossipHello function.

For Lua Script engines.

```
if(player:HasItem(192021)) then
 player:GossipMenuAddItem(6,"QUEST ITEM NPC",0, 1)
```

Thus the option "QUEST ITEM NPC" is only available if the player has item `192021`